# Saving a SecureString

Tags: .net, securestring

One of the feature requests I've got for the program I'm working on is to be able to save the list of credentials users enter in, so they can be shared around. The specific use case that inspired this request was using our program on a large corporate network, made up of fairly good LANs connected by a flaky WAN. The idea was that, instead of having our program beat against the WAN when it's down, they'd send a 'configuration' file containing the closely-guarded admin credentials, run it in each LAN and zip up the results and e-mail it back.

Yeah.

My initial instinct is to scoff at this request - saving passwords? *really?* and surely the network division of the company would prefer you to try and sell whatever WAN products they have - but it turns out one of the classes I use the credentials for can take a SecureString, and, well, it's always good to look out for ways you can save people some effort. That got me to wondering:

Is it possible to save an encrypted SecureString, so that I can save the sensitive data to a file and open it up someplace else?

What are your thoughts, Stack Overflow?

Comment: How do you mean "shared around in case of network failure"? Can you elaborate on that please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no save support in SecureString, it's intended as a mechanism to protect a in-memory managed string and is only used for interfacing with unmanaged APIs.  If a password was stored in a System.String instance, security would be less due to the nature of System.String.  The existence of garbage collection and interning would keep the password in memory longer than necessary.  Also due to the plethora of great debugging tools for .NET, it would be significantly easier to access the string through reflection or another .NET API even without the longer lifetime.

If you're going to save a password on the disk your security is pretty far compromised.  If someone has physical access to the machine, or administrator level remote access, then the best you can do is make it more difficult, but never impossible.  Use an encryption API, store it in a secure location, configure access rights.

All that aside, Merus, I'd suggest you try to improve the overall system because for a use-case like you're describing (assuming I understand it) you'd be better served to store a hash than the actual password.

Comment: I was hoping that SecureString would do the hash for me. I know better than to roll my own hashing function.

Comment: In powershell can save SecureString, any way using C# ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174425/how-does-one-securely-handle-passwords-in-a-custom-written-powershell-cmdlet

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at comparing password hash.
You would have a salt made of username and probably some other constant, followed by the string. Then, you would pass that to a hashing algorithm, like SHA1*.
For instance,

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public byte[] GetPasswordHash(string username, string password, string salt)
{
    // get salted byte[] buffer, containing username, password and some (constant) salt
    byte[] buffer;
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(salt);
        writer.Write(username);
        writer.Write(password);
        writer.Flush();

        buffer = stream.ToArray();
    }

    // create a hash
    SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create();
    return sha1.ComputeHash(buffer);
}
```

Then, you would compare the result for `GetPasswordHash(username, expectedPassword, salt)` to `GetPasswordHash(username, givenPassword, salt)`.
If you implement your own user list with usernames and passwords, you might consider only saving the hash (`GetPasswordHash(username, givenPassword, salt)`) and comparing against the saved hash.

Comment: sometimes comparing the given password is not the task but the program itself want to use passwords  to gain authorization in other system. Like a mail client use password to gain authorization in SMTP Server. what can we do in that situation

Comment: @Sankaran: Each case has its own solution. Most modern APIs accept password hashes already; some have API keys so you don't even need to know the password's hash. To use older APIs which only support using the password directly, you'd have no choice but to store the password itself. In that case, I'd use some sort of encryption, although it's pretty much futile.

Comment: MD5 is totally inappropriate as a hash algorithm choice. You need bcrypt or scrypt, or at _least_ sha1 (and even that's not really recommended).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: absolutely right. Back in '08 I didn't know that, I guess. I've updated the post accordingly to use SHA1 - because unlike bcrypt, SHA1 is built in to .Net.

Comment: @SivaSankaran Passwords should never been stored.   From a password, create a hash, store the hash in a database.   If a user, puts in the password, you hash it, validate the hash against the hast stored in the database.   A hash can't be reversed to find the password, unlike encryption's that store passwords without the use of salt.  Salt with an encryption, shouldn't be stored either.   Lot of times, I use the password as salt to encrypt and decrypt.   Unfortunately, that means, if someone forgot the password, they lose anything encrypted with that salt.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean saving the SecureString's encrypted bytes then this will not work - the key for the SecureString is tied to the user and process.  Read in those bytes in  a different process or for a different user, and there's no way to decrypt the string.

Answer (score 3):

This would defeat the point of a SecureString, which is guaranteed to reside in memory. So if you are saving it to file, you might as well save it as a normal string, since it is no longer "secure".

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the [IsolatedStorageFileStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.aspx). It specifies ways to write and store file data which can be accessed only by your assembly.

I don't think you can use SecureString on it though.

Answer (score 1):

The SecureString is not serializable so you cannot just save it with some of the delivered serializers (binary, XML, etc.)

you also cannot just access e.g. a "Password" property from a securestring object as there is no such thing.
you have to use Marshalling and a little bit of plumbing to do this.
if you want to store user credentials somewhere I suggest encrypting them on your own as this eases later development. after evaluating the SecureString approach, we decided to implement something by ourselves, but these are just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here, `SecureString` is not the best way to use in this scenario.

If I had the need to **share** the users credentials I would probably share the *username* and the *hashed + salted password*, so you would be safe and only share the **representation of a password**, not it's contents.

The simply way to this is for example use the **BCryt Library** ([where there's a .NET representation of it](http://bcrypt.codeplex.com/)) and simply host the username and password representation in a table ready to be shared

This is how you would use it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// run ADO.NET / Entity Framework / etc and query your DB with something like:
"SELECT user_id, username, password FROM [TblUsers];"

// loop through the results

sb.AppendFormat(
       "INSERT INTO [TblSharedUsers] SELECT '{0}','{1}','{2}'",            
           dr["id"], dr["username"],
           BCrypt.HashPassword(dr["password"], BCrypt.GenerateSalt(12));
       );

// then run sb.ToSTring() agains your db
```

on the client end, you can create a new `AuthenticationProvider` (so it will be easy to change when the network is not available using [IoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) and [DI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)) that reads from the `TblSharedUsers` and check the user password like

```
string userPassword = Request["password"];

"SELECT id, password FROM [TblSharedUsers] WHERE username = @usr;"

if( BCrypt.CheckPassword(userPassword, dr["password"]) )
    // User can log in
else
    // Credentials are invalid
```

I hope this helps someone with the same problem.