# How does one securely handle passwords in a custom written PowerShell cmdlet?

Tags: c#-4.0, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Assume I have a custom PowerShell Cmdlet that exports data and encrypts it using a password.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsData.Export, "SampleData")]
public class ExportSampleData : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public string Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    /* additional parameters */
}
```

How does one appropriately handle the passwords securely? For example, I'd like to prevent the value from being displayed when the administrator types it in the console. Other options include reading a file that contains an encrypted password.

I'm aware of PSCredential but that requires a user name which makes no sense in this scenario.

Comment: how did you end up using it? I have similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to obtain the password, you can use

`Read-Host` cmdlet with the`–asSecureString` parameter.

This parameter mask the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10173670/608772) a way to crypt with the computer password (works on safe machines).

Using @Christian response you can put the password to the disk like this :

```
PS > $cred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content c:\temp\password.txt
```

And retreive it with :

```
$password = Get-Content c:\temp\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential "UserName",$password
```

Comment: This is rather useful once I have password.

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of the Password parameter to SecureString; if the administrator omits the -Password parameter, PowerShell will do the right thing by prompting the administrator for the mandatory parameter and display astrisks as they type.

Ideally the implementation of your cmdlet will pass the SecureString to some API that natively supports SecureString (most secure); if not, you'll have to extract the password from the SecureString. Here's a good article on how to do that: [How to properly convert SecureString to String](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fpintos/archive/2009/06/12/how-to-properly-convert-securestring-to-string.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a C# PowerShell Cmdlet and one of the parameters requires the user to enter a password it should be obfuscated.

To do this you need to be `using System.Security;`

And then your parameter type should be `SecureString`.

So using your example:

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsData.Export, "SampleData")]
public class ExportSampleData : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
    public SecureString Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

/* additional parameters */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SecureString-Handling gives you a feeling to be a bit more secure, even if this is not the case. You can easily encrypt any SecureString like this...

```
$mrsh = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]
$ptr  = $mrsh::SecureStringToBSTR($secureString)
$pass = $mrsh::PtrToStringAuto($ptr)
```

or even without marshalling just with a webclient-object like this...

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$web = [Net.WebClient]::new()
$web.Credentials = [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new($cred.UserName,$cred.Password)
$pass = $web.Credentials.Password
```

So, in sum neither the password nor the SecureString-Password should be stores permanently as a file or anything else. Make the lifetime
of this information as short as possible - e.g. from entering the password till a cleanup of the password-variable and all its inherited variables like so:

```
Remove-Variable pass, cred, web -ea 0
```